# How to prevent IP blocking while scraping data

Tags: python, json, selenium, request

I was trying to scrape data from a website.

The code is working but the site blocks my IP address when I was trying to scrape all scrolling pages. Please let me know if there is any suggestions on how to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: I guess You could scrape slower or sth like that, because once Your ip is blocked there is nothing You can do except use a different IP

Comment: You should definitely include a `time.sleep` in the iteration. Just firing 500 requests at a site will get you banned for sure. Also, if you check the network connections, you'll see that the data is loaded from an API. Try to get the data from the API directly rather than through page requests.

Comment: I'd suggest maybe 5-10 seconds due to how most sites don't like rapid firing of requests.

Answer (score 2):

IP blocks happen when a website flags your IP as a bot or crawler. You could definitely try using proxies, they are a good workaround to this and you'll also need to rotate them to avoid detection and scrape the data in an uninterrupted manner.

Pro tip: Use residential proxies instead of data center ones to minimize your chances of getting blocked. Residential IPs belong to real devices and are much harder to detect as bots.

###### Reference: [What To Look for When Choosing A Proxy Provider?](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-what-to-look-for-when-choosing-a-proxy-provider)

Answer (score 0):

You could use proxies.

Ip-addresses can be bought very cheaply then you can iterate through a list of IP-addresses while simultaneously varying your browser and other user agent parameters.

Answer (score 0):

When first starting out with a web scraper, a common mistake is to send a request directly to the website (using a code of your choice), and the website’s response will depend on your activity. Many websites have developed systems to detect bots and web scrapers, and if you are caught, you risk having your IP address blocked and being unable to make a request for an extended period of time. That is an issue.

So you use IP proxy this time to hide your true IP address. In fact, you used multiple proxy servers to cycle it through, allowing you to make requests much faster. However, there is another issue. Yes, Captcha is another issue you must deal with.

As a result, you’ll need to add a Captcha solver layer to your scraper.

This is where [ScraperApi](https://www.scraperapi.com/?fp_ref=discount) comes in. It simplifies all of the complicated processes for you. All you have to do is request scraperapi to browse a URL and return a clean HTML page without worrying about IP or captcha. Scraperapi can be used to create an effective web scraper for complex web pages with forms and js.